# Making sure Python package is installed at least with one extra

Tags: python, setuptools

I have generic http client library that provides both sync and async interfaces. Underneath it uses either `requests` or `aiohttp`. Most of my projects use either sync or async version hence there is no reason to require both `aiohttp` and `requests` in `setup.py`. To address this I have the following `extras_require` in `setup.py`:

```
extras_require={
    "async": ["aiohttp"],
    "sync": ["requests"],
    "all": ["aiohttp", "requests"],
}
```

The only issue is that if you install my http client package without any extras it does not make sense really since you won't be able to use both versions due to missing dependencies.

Is there a way to verify that my Python package is being installed with at least on of the extras specified? May be some kind of hook in my `setup.py`?

Comment: Extras are called extras for a reason - they aren't required. Your package obviously requires at least one dependency, so select one and include it in the default requirements, the other being optional. BTW I don't see why not installing both and messing with `extras` at all. Sync and async versions have different interfaces anyway.

Comment: I don't like all my pure-async users to have `requests` installed - look unclean. Are there any post-install hooks with setuptools?

Answer (score 1):

No straightforward solution that I am aware of.

A more involved solution I can think of, would be to publish two other projects named `something-sync` and `something-async` that have only one single dependency each: `something[sync]` and `something[async]` respectively (assuming your project is named `something`). This would be relatively easy to implement with good CI/CD tooling.

Comment: While it will eventually work, I believe it's too much overhead. Both sync and async interface use several common modules which will need to be refactored to a 3rd repo using this approach. Every repo will needs to be published in PyPi, with proper verisons pinned, etc. And we didn't even get to CI yet :)

Comment: "_Both sync and async interface use several common modules which will need to be refactored to a 3rd repo using this approach._" No, this shouldn't be the case, unless I misunderstood something. In my example you wouldn't need to change anything to the main `something` project. The other 2 would contain no actual code, only the `install_requires=['something[sync]']` line has actual value.

Comment: "_And we didn't even get to CI yet_". You could actually do without it: just never release newer versions of `something-sync` and `something-async`. It should all still work. New installations would still get the newest version of `something`. The users that are comfortable enough to install a specific version of `something` are also likely comfortable enough to understand the concept of `extras` and can use `pip install something[sync]==1.2.3` without difficulty.

Comment: Obvioulsy this kind of setup might not be worth the work for so little gain. Just instruct the users of your package to install the right _extras_. There really is no easy way to do it otherwise.

Comment: Apologies, I misred your original answer. Indeed, this approach is neat. The idea of never releasing updates to `something-sync` is problematic e.g. with pipenv flow: you update pinned versions of your first-level dependencies and then re-lock. Hence "no releases" approach will fail to update underlying version here.

Comment: "_with pipenv flow: you update pinned versions of your first-level dependencies and then re-lock_". I don't use _pipenv_ in particular, but in genereal the idea of pinning only the top level dependencies is strange to me. This argument doesn't hold to me in any workflow. Let's say an indirect dependency gets a new release for a security hole. Do you really wait for a new release from your top level dependency? I must be missing something here... In my mind the compromise would be to release a new version of `something-sync` only when `something` gets a new *major* release (assuming _semver_).

Comment: I guess we see things differently. I prefer this philosophy: https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/a-better-pip-workflow

Comment: We're probably out of scope already considering the original question. But I find this topic interesting, so for the sake of the argument... No matter what one uses, whether it be pipenv's Pipfile, setuptools' setup.cfg, or poetry's pyproject.toml, they will have to consider dependencies beyond the immediate ones. By that I mean, that they will sooner or later have to either pin or restrict the version numbers of indirect dependencies, and this has to be done manually with intent and after careful thought, including the extras. Finally `pipenv update --outdated` should help with that, right?

Comment: I see a point in what you are saying. Depends on a stage of your project and product preconditions I assume. `pipenv update --outdate` should do the trick indeed.